# A bit confusing compiler error message around Boxed Future in Rust

Tags: rust, future

I don't seem to understand the compiler error message here. For the following snippet

```rust
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::future::Future;

fn give_future<'a>(x : &'a i32) -> Pin<impl Future<Output=&'a i32> + 'a> {
    Box::pin(async move { x })
}
```

it says the following

```
error[E0277]: `[async block@src/lib.rs]` cannot be unpinned
 --> src/lib.rs:7:47
  |
  | fn give_future<'a>(x : &'a i32) -> Pin<impl Future<Output=&'a i32> + 'a> {
  |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `[async block@src/lib.rs]`
  |
  = note: consider using the `pin!` macro
          consider using `Box::pin` if you need to access the pinned value outside of the current scope
  = note: required for `Box<[async block@src/lib.rs]>` to implement `Future`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

From what I understand, `Pinx<Box<impl Future>>` is being returned as `Pin<impl Future>`. Why isn't the compiler just saying that?

Comment: The compiler doesn't say that because there's no reason `Box<...>` definitely cannot satisfy `impl Future`, so the types are not necessarily incorrect for that specific reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> From what I understand, `Pin<Box<impl Future>>` is being returned as `Pin<impl Future>`. Why isn't the compiler just saying that?

The basis for what you've written could be a perfectly viable thing to do. Probably not with `Pin` in particular (since it is quite narrow and nuanced in its functionality) but masquerading `Box<T>` as `impl Trait` is a thing that is done all the time to avoid leaking internal details and can work because traits are commonly implemented on `Box<T>`s where `T: Trait`.

So the compiler is simply trying to satisfy your request. To do so it only needs to verify that `Box<T>` implements `Future`, and [it has an implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-Future-for-Box%3CF,+A%3E) but only if that `T` implements [`Unpin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unpin.html). And thus you get the error.